# div content after html() is not showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dom

I've got an issue with an ajax call and .html(), as you can see with the javascript below i'm using the geoloc callback to make a ajax call and refresh the content of a div.
The id of the div can be either "result-shops-ajax-desktop" or "result-shops-ajax-mobile" and in my case the php variable $type = "desktop"
The problem is that the content of the div is not reloaded despite the use of .html()
My ajax call is working because msg.response got the content i want. The .html() seems to work because the alert show the content of msg.response but I can't see it on the page :/
Another thing is weird when i put directly the id of the div, the content is shown, but when i echo the $type it's not working despite the fact that the html produced is good (the id of the div is "result-shops-ajax-desktop").

I hoped i made myself clear with my bad english, i would really appreciate any help for this weird issue.

Thanks !

Here is the javascript in my php file :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            function geolocShow(position) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('shops/index/checkavailability'); ?>",
                    dataType : "json",
                    data: "sku=<?php echo $product->getSku(); ?>&lat="+position.coords.latitude+"&lng="+position.coords.longitude,
                    success: function(msg){
                        $("#result-shops-ajax-<?php echo trim($type); ?>").html(msg.response);
                        alert($("#result-shops-ajax-<?php echo trim($type); ?>").html());
                    }
                });
            }

            if(navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocShow);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

The html generated:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    function geolocShow(position) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/shops/index/checkavailability/",
            dataType : "json",
            data: "sku=abc&lat="+position.coords.latitude+"&lng="+position.coords.longitude,
            success: function(msg){
                $("#result-shops-ajax-desktop").html(msg.response);
                alert($("#result-shops-ajax-desktop").html());
            }
        });
    }

    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocShow);
    }
});
```

Comment: have you tried `$("#result-shops-ajax-<?php echo trim($type); ?>").load(msg.response);`?

Comment: Is the `div` visible or is it perhaps hidden using css?

Comment: Are your sure what you have get in msg.response is HTML, try to alert msg.response

Comment: try .text() instead of html()

Comment: Better to show the actual code in the page source as well, not just the php that is supposed to genereta it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. load() is not working, the alert don't show the content anymore and nothing is shown on the page. The div is visible in css, I also tried without success reload(), hide() then show(). I got html in msg.response (that's what is shown in the alert after the .html()), plus its working when i put directly the id of the div without $type, really weird... I added the generated code in the original post.

Comment: Please show your server side thml data... i think your problem in server side

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**  `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`  this line change to `$(window).load(function(){`